# asp.net identity core - there's no controller classes found on my project using vs 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-identity

asp.net identity core - there's no controller classes found on my project using vs 2019

[image]

no account controller was generated so if i need to edit on login/logout etc need to write the logic again from scratsh

[image]

but in asp.net mvc5 was different and there were a controller code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net core identity default application, there are no visible stuff(controllers,views)  related to the identity management. You have to add them to your project as Scaffolded items.

Right click on your project then click on "Add" => "Add new Scaffolded Item".
Then in "Add new Scaffolded item" screen select "Identity" and click "Add" button.
[image]

Then in the next UI , you can choose whatever the file you need to modify.

[image]

Please note that this scaffolded identity is not using controller concept, they are Razor pages.

Comment: You would think we know this already. Thanks for this lifesaver.